# Where to get Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll 1.2.0.0

Tags: enterprise-library

I was given A Visual Studio project written  that has a reference to the dll in the Windows GAC

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll 1.2.0.0
```

which I don't have installed on my machine

The same dll is not anywhere in the project directory.

I downloaded Enterprise Library V6 but the dll is version 3.0.1304.0

I was able to locate  other dll versions

2.0.505.0

2.0.414.0

I change the references in the projects from 1.2.0.0 to a later version but  the  code isn't backward compatible so I need the exact dll version.

Where do I get this dll?

I googled for it but one I got is a virus, the other was 2.0.505.0

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the Unity Application Block 1.2:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=701

Once installed, the file is located under `Microsoft Unity Application Block 1.2\Bin.`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to install all the Enterprise Library Installers to find which one contained that version.

The version it was in was Enterprise Library 4.1. I downloaded it and extracted it to a folder and was able to obtain the dll.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647292.aspx)